# is it possible global variable in couchbase javascript view?

Tags: javascript, couchbase

i have my reduce method and i would like to time how much it takes so i wanted basically to do something like:

```
function(key, values, rereduce) {
  var start_time = new Date();

  // my calcs here.

  var totallength = 0; // this is wrong... any global variables or closure?
  var totaltime = 0; // this is wrong... any global variables or closure?

  time_calc_took = new Date() - start_time;
  totallength += values.length;
  totaltime += time_calc_took;
  return([totallength, totaltime, someother_results]);
}
```

however as totallength and totaltime are not global variables i cannot really measure my view performance, i want to know how much time it takes for it to run on a different count of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are no global variables inside a function. It has only local variables. Global variables only could be defined in global scope (outside of function). But in couchbase you can't define any variables outside of reduce function.
2. If you want to measure view performance your code is complitly wrong, because you'll just measure a part of it, because this function can be called multiple times. Read couchbase docs about reduce function (see links below).
3. At last, the code you've written will not measure view performance, because it can only measure view indexing performance. And view performance is not equal to indexing performance, basically because indexing process in most cases runs in background, and it not affects view performance.

I recommend you to read this [document](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#views-and-indexes) about views and how do they work. Also pay attention to [paragraph](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.0/#handling-rereduce) about reduce functions.

UPD:
Global variables couldn't exist in context of reduce function. If you carefully read documentation about view and it's reduce function, you should understand that reduce function can be called multiple times on different servers in cluster. So you can't define any variable that will be global on multiple servers in cluster. You can only operate with variables that you return. Also you need to handle `rereduce` in your reduce function, if you don't, you'll count time of lastest reduce's rereduce and ignore all previous values.

Better way to measure view's performance is to genereate loadtest and operate with maximum operations/second, not absolute time of view indexing process. If you need to meaasure indexing speed - query your view with `stale=false` param that will force couchbase to update index before returning result, so time of that query will represent time taken for mapping and reducing your result (i.e. you can even use curl or web browser). But in real application you need to avoid queries with `stale=false`.

To tune your reduce code, you can just measure it performance in browser, or better in nodejs. Just copy your reduce function and call it with your map data. If you optimize your code in browser, your code will be faster in CB. You can even find online jsvascript map-reduce emulators.

Comment: (1) question is if there is another way to do it.
(2) I mention in the code its wrong this is why i' m looking for global vars at the first place.  // this is wrong... any global variables or closure?
(3) I was looking for a way to measure this code, as reduce function runs only in background (i called it view as indeed reduce and maps are part of the view concept in CB) and not in the query phase, so i'm interested to know about its performance as i would want to tune that code with relation to how CB works with it and the data in my server.

Comment: I've updated my answer. If I need to explain something - just ask. Also you can view my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972085/couchbase-rereduce-questions. May be it will be also helpful.